# PHP and server-to-server communication in LAN

Tags: php, linux, networking, load-balancing, openstack

I am doing a project that has to incorporate load-balancing using OpenStack platform. It boils down to spreading browser requests, that execute calculation-heavy scripts, across several virtual machines running some distro of Linux.

Due to all installation attempts of OpenStack going horribly wrong, I ended up using TryStack.org, which is a free and working environment. The obvious problem here is, it offers very limited resources. For instance, I can have only 1 floating (external) IP, which can be assigned to only 1 single instance (virtual machine) and there are measures that make it impossible to change it via API.

Due to those limitations, I have to work with a very peculiar setup: I have a network with nodes A, B and C. A, B and C can communicate with each other, but only A has an external IP, ie. is accessible by browser.

[(illustration)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOjEv.png)

Therefore, I have to:

1. direct all browser requests to A,
2. have A request (and wait for) execution of calculation-heavy scripts on B/C,
3. make B/C send back results once they are finished
4. and finally have A dress results in HTML and send response back to the browser.

Is there any mechanism in PHP that can do 2. and 3.? If not, what (Linux-compatible) language/technology can do that? (I have already written almost all of the code in PHP, but I suppose I can switch.)

Alternatively: is there some other free OpenStack service that would allow me to give every instance an IP (in which case the spreading problem could be solved via simple redirects)?

Comment: Well, how do you do http requests with php? Take a look at phps `cURL` extension or some wrapper for it like `guzzle`. You can decide which system to ask, make the request, collect the result and post process it. No problem there.

Comment: @arkascha It seems that was exactly the solution I needed. Feel free to turn this comment into answer - while I haven't tested it on TryStack yet, I have a feeling it will work, and I'll accept your answer. (Ironically, earlier in the project I had to carefully install php-cURL, twice, because of guzzle errors - since guzzle is part of OpenCloud SDK.)

Comment: All fine, glad I could push you onto the right track with a few thoughts on how to do a network request.

Comment: @arkascha Yes, it seems to be working as intended. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [arkascha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1248114/arkascha) advised in the comments, [I used `curl`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to simply send a page request from A to B/C, and then parsed the page using text manipulation.